# rename() function differs in levels of indirection from int

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a code that uses linked lists and files, to maintain actions (functions) that are given on a text file, instead of receiving them from the user.

For some reason i'm encountering an error which says:

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   **Error C2040   'rename': 'hw_component *(char *,char *,hw_component *)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int (const char *,const char *)'**  EX5_313410961   c:\users\edave\source\repos\ex5_313410961\ex5_313410961\shahar_connection.c 172"

I'm having trouble understanding if the problem is the actual function `rename()` or because of the `actions()` function.

The code is very long so ill post the relevant section only.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NAME_LENGTH 200

typedef struct hw_component
{
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    int copies;
    struct hw_component *next;
}hw_component;

hw_component *create_component(char* name,int copies)
{
    if (name != NULL && strlen(name) > NAME_LENGTH)
        return NULL;
    hw_component *comp = (hw_component*)malloc(sizeof(hw_component));
    if (comp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: memory allocation failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(comp->name, name);
    comp->copies = copies;
    comp->next = NULL;
    return comp;
}

hw_component *add_sort(hw_component* head, int copies, char *name)
{
    hw_component *iter, *prev = NULL;
    hw_component *new_comp = create_component(name, copies);
    if (head == NULL)
        return new_comp;
    if (strcmp(new_comp->name, head->name) < 0)
    {
        new_comp->next = head;
        return new_comp;
    }
    iter = head;
    while (iter != NULL && strcmp(iter->name, new_comp->name) < 0)
    {
        prev = iter;
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    prev->next = new_comp;
    new_comp->next = iter;
    return head;
}

hw_component *initialize(char *argv[])
{
    hw_component *list_of_comp = NULL;
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char dolar[2] = "$";
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: opening %s failed\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        char str[400], *token, *str_num;
        fgets(str, 400, fp);
        int numb;
        token = strtok(str,dolar);
        str_num = strtok(NULL, dolar);
        numb = atoi(str_num);
        list_of_comp=add_sort(list_of_comp, numb, token);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return list_of_comp;
}

void finalize(hw_component *head, char *argv[])
{
    hw_component *temp;
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int temp_num;
    char *str,*num_str;
    fp = fopen(argv[3], "w");
    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: opening %s failed\n", argv[3]);
        while (head!=NULL)
        {
            temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            free(temp);
        }
    }
    while (head!=NULL)
    {
        temp = head;
        fprintf(fp,"%s $$$ %d\n",temp->name,temp->copies);
        head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

hw_component *remove_comp_by_name(hw_component *head_comp, char comp_name[NAME_LENGTH + 1])
{
    hw_component *temp_ptr = head_comp;
    hw_component *prev_ptr;
    hw_component *zero_copies_check = head_comp;


    if (head_comp == NULL)
    {
        return head_comp;
    }

    if (strcmp(temp_ptr->name, comp_name) == 0)
    {
        head_comp = head_comp->next;
        free(temp_ptr);
        return head_comp;
    }

    while (temp_ptr != NULL && strcmp(temp_ptr->name, comp_name) != 0)
    {
        prev_ptr = temp_ptr;
        temp_ptr = temp_ptr->next;
    }

    if (temp_ptr != NULL)
    {
        prev_ptr->next = temp_ptr->next;
        free(temp_ptr);
    }

    while (zero_copies_check != NULL)
    {
        if (zero_copies_check->copies == 0)
        {
            free(zero_copies_check);
        }

        zero_copies_check = zero_copies_check->next;
    }

    return head_comp;

}

hw_component *rename(char old_name[NAME_LENGTH], char new_name[NAME_LENGTH], hw_component *head_comp)
{
    hw_component *temp_comp = head_comp;
    int num_of_copies = 0;

    if (head_comp == NULL)
    {
        return head_comp;
    }

    while (temp_comp != NULL && strcmp(temp_comp->name, old_name) != 0)
    {
        temp_comp = temp_comp->next;
    }

    num_of_copies = temp_comp->copies;

    head_comp=remove_comp_by_name(head_comp, old_name);
    head_comp=add_sort(head_comp, num_of_copies, new_name);
    return head_comp;
}

hw_component *return_comp(hw_component *head, char name_of_comp[], int copies)
{
    hw_component *temp_comp = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return head;
    }

    while (temp_comp != NULL && strcmp(temp_comp->name, name_of_comp) != 0)
    {
        temp_comp = temp_comp->next;
    }
    if (temp_comp != NULL)
    {
        temp_comp->copies += copies;
    }
    else
    {
        add_sort(head, name_of_comp, copies);
    }
    return head;
}

int choose_act(char *str)
{
    char init[12] = "Initialize ", rename[8]="Rename ",fire[6]="Fire ";
    char retu[24] = "Returned_from_customer ", prod[12]="Production " ,fatal[19]="Fatal_malfunction ";
    char finalize[] = "Finalize";
    if (strcmp(str,init)==0)
        return 1;
    if (strcmp(str, rename)==0)
        return 2;
    if (strcmp(str, retu)==0 || strcmp(str, prod)==0)
        return 3;
    if (strcmp(str, fire)==0 || strcmp(str, fatal)==0)
        return 4;
    if (strcmp(str, finalize)==0)
        return 5;
}
void actions(char *argv[])
{
    char dolar[2] = "$";
    hw_component *head;
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char str[400], *token, *name, *old_name;
    int choise = 0, numb;
    fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: opening %s failed\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        fgets(str, 400, fp);
        token = strtok(str,dolar);
        choise = choose_act(token);
        head = initialize(argv);
        switch (choise)
        {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            old_name = strtok(str, dolar);
            name = strtok(str, dolar);
            printf("%s %s", old_name, name);
            head=rename(old_name,name,head);
            break;
        case 3:
            name = strtok(str, dolar);
            numb = atoi(strtok(str, dolar));
            head=return_comp(head, name, numb);
            break;
        case 4:
            name = strtok(str, dolar);
            numb = atoi(strtok(str, dolar));
            head=fatal_maf(head, name, numb);
            break;
        case 5:
            finalize(head,argv);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
int check_argc(int argc)
{
    int numb = argc;
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Error: invalid number of arguments (<%d> instead of 3)\n", numb);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int res = 0;
    res=check_argc(argc);
    if (res == 1)
        actions(argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You library already defines a function called [`rename()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rename), which is prototyped in and included by adding `stdio.h`, which is creating the conflict with your user-defined function.

As per the lined manual, the signature of the library-defined `rename()` is `int rename (const char *, const char*)`, whereas as er your function definition, you have a signature as `hw_component *rename(char *, char *, hw_component *)` - which does not match and your compiler is showing you correct warning (and error) message.

**Solution**: Use a different name for your function.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot name your custom function `rename` while including `stdio.h`, because the name collides with the standard library function `rename`. Name your own function something different.

The standard function is

```
int rename(const char *old, const char *new);
```

So it has type `int (const char *, const char *)`, the same type that the compiler is complaining about a conflict with.